# Delphi XE DLL in C#. Marshalling struct with WideString

Tags: c#, delphi, pinvoke

Code in my Delphi dll:

```
...

type
  TPrototype = packed record
    TypeControl: Integer;
    Left: Integer;
    Top: Integer;
    Width: Integer;
    Height: Integer;
    Name: WideString;
    Caption: WideString;
  end;

...

procedure AssignPrototype(var Prototype: TPrototype); stdcall;
begin

  FillChar(Prototype, SizeOf(Prototype), 0);

  with Prototype do begin
    TypeControl := 1;
    Left   := 10;
    Top    := 20;
    Height := 30;
    Width  := 30;
    Caption := 'mycaption';
    Name := 'myname'
  end;
end;

...

exports
 AssignPrototype;

begin
end.
```

And code in C#:

```
...
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode, Pack=1)]
        public struct Prototype
        {
                public Int32 TypeControl;
                public Int32 Left;
                public Int32 Top;
                public Int32 Width;
                public Int32 Height;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
                public string Name;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]
                public string Caption;
        }
...
[DllImport("DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall]
public static extern void AssignPrototype(ref Prototype prototype);
...
```

But it doesnt work. If in Delphi 7 Name and Caption is an array [1..50] of `Char` and I use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 50)]` it works, but a maximum of 256 chars is very few and Name, Caption with cyrillic chars is null.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: Have you tried it without [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]? I have a few Delphi dlls exposing com interfaces and string<->WideString works without any special MarshalAs attributes

Comment: @Mike You'll need to review your existing code. `string` is by default marshalled as `LPCSTR` or `LPCWSTR`. That's different from `BSTR`.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes, I realize that, which is why the comment only stayed there for about 1 minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly as is when I run it. I expect that your actual code differs in some way from that in the question. Use the code in the question, and the string values will arrive back in your C# program.

I have a few comments and suggestions for improvement:

1. `CharSet.Unicode` serves no purpose here. A `BStr` is always UTF-16 encoded.
2. The use of `packed` is inefficient. I suggest that you remove that.
3. The parameter should really be an `out` parameter.